# Qt QML How to manually select word in TextArea by double click

Tags: qt, qml

double click selects words, but i'd like to customise it to, for example, select the $1000 term.

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TextArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: "hello, try to select the $1000 prize!"
        font.pointSize: 14
    } 
}
```

For example, by somehow overriding `selectWord` or by overriding `onDoubleClicked` or by somehow adding my own `MouseArea` that *doesn't* break the existing `TextArea` functionality.

Not sure how to do this.

Thanks for any help.

### update

I tried adding a `MouseArea` but it didnt work. Example;

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TextArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: "hello, try to select the $1000 prize!"
        font.pointSize: 14

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            propagateComposedEvents: true
            onClicked: 
            {
                // attempt to get an event on click without
                // affecting the TextArea. But it breaks selection.
                console.log("clicked some text")
                mouse.accepted = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update 2

I think this problem is a version of the long-running Qt problem that you can't have some kind of "event observer" whose job is to check events but not stop them from continuing their normal operation.

If i had an event observer, i could make it "observe" the TextArea and do something on click or double click.

So, here goes trying to make one....

toucharea.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QTime>

class TouchArea : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQuickItem *target READ target WRITE setTarget NOTIFY targetChanged)

public:

    QTime _lastMousePress;
    int   _clickThresholdMS = 300;

    bool eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent *event) override
    {
        // if false this will allow the event to continue as normal
        // if true it will stop the event propagating
        bool handled = false;

        // https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum
        QEvent::Type t = event->type();
        switch (t)
        {
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
            break;
        case QEvent::KeyPress:
        case QEvent::KeyRelease:
            {
                QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
                qDebug("key press %d", keyEvent->key());
            }
            break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
            {
                qDebug() << "mouse press";
                _lastMousePress.start();
                break;
            }
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
            {
                qDebug() << "mouse release";
                int dt = _lastMousePress.elapsed();

                if (dt < _clickThresholdMS)
                {
                    qDebug() << "mouse click";
                    emit clicked();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return handled;
    }

    QQuickItem *target() const { return _target; }

    void setTarget(QQuickItem *target) 
    {
        qDebug() << "set target";
        if (_target == target) return;

        if (_target)
            _target->removeEventFilter(this);

        _target = target;

        if (_target)
            _target->installEventFilter(this);

        emit targetChanged();
    }

signals:

    void targetChanged();
    void clicked();

private:

    QQuickItem* _target = 0;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>

#include "toucharea.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<TouchArea>("App", 1, 0, "TouchArea");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

import App 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480


    TextArea
    {
        id: tarea
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: "hello, try to select the $1000 prize!"
        font.pointSize: 14

        MouseArea
        {
            enabled: false
            anchors.fill: parent

            TouchArea
            {
                target: parent
                onClicked: console.log("captured a click")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well it nearly worked. I can only capture my synthetic *click* if we `handled` the event in `eventFilter`. When not `handled` the filter does not see the `MouseButtonRelease`.

Why is this. I was expecting this to be the first handler encountered *before* the other QtQuick items get to see it.

Any help?

Comment: Did you try to search that in [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textarea.html#select-method) first?

Comment: @folibis Sure, but it has no indication how to override doubleclick or otherwise. If i add my own `MouseArea` then `TextArea` breaks.

Comment: You should clarify your question as this remark completely changes the question

Comment: @folibis you're right. I added what ive tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way;

### Step 1, define an Observer class for events

observer.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QTime>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class Observer : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QTime _lastMousePress;
    int   _clickThresholdMS = 300;

    Observer()
    {
        setFiltersChildMouseEvents(true);
    }

    bool childMouseEventFilter(QQuickItem*, QEvent *event) override
    {
        // if false this will allow the event to continue as normal
        // if true it will stop the event propagating
        bool handled = false;

        // https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum
        QEvent::Type t = event->type();
        switch (t)
        {
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
            break;
        case QEvent::KeyPress:
        case QEvent::KeyRelease:
            {
                QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
                qDebug("key press %d", keyEvent->key());
            }
            break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
            {
                //qDebug() << "mouse press";
                _lastMousePress.start();
            }
            break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
            {
                //qDebug() << "mouse release";
                int dt = _lastMousePress.elapsed();

                if (dt < _clickThresholdMS)
                {
                    //qDebug() << "mouse click";
                    emit clicked();
                }
            }
            break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick:
            {
                //QMouseEvent* mevent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
                //qDebug() << "mouse double click";
                emit doubleClicked();
                handled = true;
            }
            break;
        }

        return handled;
    }

signals:

    void clicked();
    void doubleClicked();

};
```

### Step 2, put this in main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>

#include "observer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Observer>("App", 1, 0, "Observer");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

### Step 3, use Observer to detect event

Detect whichever event you want, then make it do what you need, for example, for double click to select a wider class of characters in `TextArea`;

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

import App 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Observer
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onDoubleClicked:
        {
            tarea.selectWord();

            var s = tarea.selectionStart
            var e = tarea.selectionEnd

            function allowed(c)
            {
                if (c == "$" || c == "#") return true;
                if (c >= "0" && c <= "9") return true;
                if (c.toUpperCase() != c.toLowerCase()) return true;
                return false;
            }

            while (allowed(tarea.getText(s-1, s))) tarea.select(--s, e);
            while (allowed(tarea.getText(e, e+1))) tarea.select(s, ++e);
        }

        TextArea
        {
            id: tarea
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: "hello, try to select the #$$$1000###$foo prize!"
            font.pointSize: 14
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't think you would be able to properly catch/release the events on a complex object such as a text *word*. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do this with [TapHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-taphandler.html):

```js
    import QtQuick 2.15
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

    TextField {
        width: parent.width

        selectByMouse: true

        TapHandler {
            grabPermissions: PointerHandler.TakeOverForbidden
            onDoubleTapped: (eventPoint) => {
                print("taptap");
                eventPoint.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that I experienced both that the double-click = select string on `TextField` did and did not work after the above. Click+drag to select always worked though.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any solution that would preserve the `TextArea` behavior, just on the QML side. I would instead try to wrap, inherit or reimplement the component on the C++ side, to add what you want.

- Inheriting may be tricky, as few Qt classes are meant to be inherited directly, looking at `QQuickTextArea` and `QQuickTextEdit` source, it might be challenging
- Reimplementing can be some work, but that would probably be the option I would go for, while keeping the logic and code there to a minimum. `QQuickTextArea` seems a good base/reference as smaller/simpler than `QQuickTextArea` (which in turn uses TextArea internally)

Two key elements to that:

- Events management (mouse, selection, ...)
- Rendering of the component, based on Qt OpenGL wrapper classes (QSG* Scene graph classes). It is a bit obscure, but there are some tutorials and presentations out there about it. And you may be able to just copy-paste the original code.

For both, I would recommend digging into the source code:

- `QQuickTextEdit`: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquicktextedit.cpp
- `QQuickTextArea`: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/quicktemplates2/qquicktextarea.cpp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, im using `TextArea` 1.4 because i need the cut & paste dialog box not there in controls2. I tried copying the QML sources in and changing them, but too many private sections. I've has a go at a different C++ approach. But it doersnt work.